# Android Kernel - Unable to activate CONFIG_USB_ETH=y in the kernel dot config

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, usb, android-source, android-kernel

I am trying to configure Android Kernel (msm-4.4)to have USB-CDC Ethernet Support in order to implement USB tethering in the low level. What I want to do is to migrate what's done in the following link to Android: https://developer.ridgerun.com/wiki/index.php/How_to_use_USB_device_networking

The following are already enabled in the `.config`:

```
CONFIG_USB=y
CONFIG_SND_USB=y
CONFIG_USB_SUPPORT=y
CONFIG_USB_GADGET=y
CONFIG_USB_CONFIGFS_UEVENT=y
```

However, when I add the following

```
CONFIG_USB_ETH=y
CONFIG_USB_ETH_EEM=y
```

Resulting `.config` has CONFIG_USB_CONFIGFS_UEVENT disabled:

```
CONFIG_USB_ETH=y
# CONFIG_USB_CONFIGFS_UEVENT is not set
```

which results in kernel compilation errors:

```
In function 'gadgets_make':
error: 'gadget_index' undeclared (first use in this function)
  gadget_index++;
  ^
note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
In function 'gadgets_drop':
error: 'struct gadget_info' has no member named 'dev'
  if (gi->dev) {
        ^
```

When I try to compile CONFIG_USB_ETH as a module, kernel compilation succeeds, but the resulting .config don't have it as enabled:

```
# CONFIG_USB_ETH is not set
```

I want to understand why something bizarre like this happens. I searched through the entire Android source code and couldn't find which triggers this blocking behavior.

Please have a look at the following Kconfigs if you require:

https://github.com/android-linux-stable/msm-4.4/blob/5a05099fd7feedfa07a75720669caf5f374810d4/drivers/usb/gadget/legacy/Kconfig

https://github.com/android-linux-stable/msm-4.4/blob/5a05099fd7feedfa07a75720669caf5f374810d4/drivers/usb/gadget/legacy/Kconfig

Any guidance to identify this problem is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `CONFIG_USB_NET_CDC_EEM=y` instead of `CONFIG_USB_ETH=y`.

`CONFIG_USB_ETH` is not compatible with `CONFIG_USB_CONFIGFS_UEVENT`